# Which is the right method to handle oauth2.0 done in server using Ionic framework?

Tags: angularjs, oauth-2.0, ionic-framework

I am creating an Ionic app which has multiple 3rd party integration. I already have a java server which does the oauth2 authentication for the 3rd parties and redirect to the callback url in the server itself.

Now my task is to open back the app page after the server callback url is done.

I have tried the following method:
 monitoring the url changes in app using ionic and redirect after the successful callback.

Which is the best way to handle this sitn.

Thanks.

Answer (score 3):

Frankly, I haven't done anything like this. But to my mind, you can check [ngcordova oauth](http://ngcordova.com/docs/plugins/oauth/) implementation for ideas.

```
   var browserRef = window.open(your_url);

   browserRef.addEventListener("loadstart", function(event) {
       //your code
   });
   browserRef.addEventListener('exit', function(event) {
       deferred.reject("The sign in flow was canceled");
   });
```

Check [oauth.js source](https://github.com/nraboy/ng-cordova-oauth/blob/master/src/oauth.js) for more details.

Moreover, you can find the sample of using this implementation [on this page.](http://ngcordova.com/docs/plugins/oauth/)

Comment: Thanks. I have done the same thing currently in my app. But i feel monitoring the url changes is not the right way to handle it, thats y i added this questian.

Comment: Could you specify, why monitoring URL changes aren't the right way? Just interesting in cons of this way.

Comment: when i use this method , the url is getting changed multiple times and event gets fired unnecessarily, till the last url which I want to close. I want some method in which the url is closed from the servlet itself which sends a status back to the ionic app.

Answer (score 2):

http://mcgivery.com/using-custom-url-schemes-ionic-framework-app/

Above link may help you. If I am thinking correctly what you want?

Comment: Thanks, but thats not what I was looking for . I need to open my java servlet and then perform authentication in a window and then close it after success or error. The ionic app should get the status back also